# determine clear value event in PivotTableAfterValueChange

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-grid, vba

I have an excel pivotgrid (connected to writeback enabled SSAS cube).

When i clear contents (select range & press DEL) of cells it fires PivotTableAfterValueChange event, but Value property of affected cells stil contained old value.

Moreover, CellChanged property stays xlCellNotChanged.

Is there any way to determine such clear event, to override existing behaviour?

Comment: You can have a look at the MSDN site to see what events are available for pivot tables: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198138.aspx

Comment: already did it, but problem isn't in finding event to be fired (it fires), but determine fact of clearing cell contents (press delete, or paste empty value).
PivotGrid, in contrast to regular cell, don't clear value in this case, just discard any unapproved changes. 
i need override this logic.